# Get an array of forms in java script using prototype

Tags: javascript, forms, prototypejs

My document contains more than one forms. How can I get an array of all forms using prototype?

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
 <form id="form1">
  <!-- Other stuffs here -->
 </form>
 <form id="form2">
  <!-- Other stuffs here -->
 </form>
 <form id="form3">
  <!-- Other stuffs here -->
 </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using prototype:

```
$$('form')
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `document.forms` property.

Comment: @OP: If you do it this way and want to use any of Prototype's extensions on one of the forms, be sure to run it through `$` first, e.g. NOT `data = document.forms[0].serialize();`, but instead `data = $(document.forms[0]).serialize();` The former will work on Firefox, Chrome, and some others but fail on IE. Whereas that's done for you if you use `$$` (see Dan's answer). Either is totally fine and works well.